# Python : Why use "list[:]" when "list" refers to same thing?

Tags: python, slice

Consider a list `>>> l=[1,2,3]`.

What is the benefit of using `>>> l[:]` when `>>> l` prints the same thing as former does?

Thanks.

Comment: What causes you to think they're the same thing?  Did you use the `id()` function to confirm that?

Comment: They printed the same value. That made me think so. I was wondering that why should one waste time in writing extra characters when we get same output without [:]. Never knew about `id()`. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Dharmit: It's ok, don't be intimidated! You are learning and its obvious to ask such question. It was a good question. We all begin somewhere, lest we forget that we also used to ask such questions when we were learning :)

Comment: Thanks. That's the reason I preferred asking on SO. On forums, at times, people get angry for asking very basic questions. :(

Comment: @Dharmit: Best to avoid such people and continue learning. Best of luck!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It creates a (shallow) copy.

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> m = l[:]
>>> n = l
>>> l.append(4)
>>> m
[1, 2, 3]
>>> n
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> n is l
True
>>> m is l
False
```

Comment: +20 for something this basic (that has propably been asked before here, has been explained in a hundred other questions using it, is in the official tutorial and propably most others, etc.)...

Answer (score 12):

`l[:]` is called slice notation.  It can be used to extract only some of the elements in the list, but in this case the bounds are omitted so the entire list is returned, but because of the slice, this will actually be a reference to a different list than `l` that contains the same elements.  This technique is often used to make shallow copies or clones.

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists