# Why is this an endless for loop?

Tags: python, list, loops, infinite-loop

I just went through the Looping Techniques Chapter of the Python docs tutorial and I have a question regarding this boy here: `[:]`

I learned that it takes the start and end index of a string, so:

```
text = "This is text"
text[:] # will return the whole text "This is text" and
tex[:4] # will return "This".
```

But when I saw this code here...

```
words = ['cat', 'dog', 'cowcowcow']
for w in words[:]:  # Loop over a slice copy of the entire list.
    if len(w) > 6:
        words.insert(0, w)
print words
```

Output:

```
['cowcowcow', 'cat', 'dog', 'cowcowcow']
```

...I didn't understand the meaning of `[:]` in the for loop. I would just write

```
for w in words:
```

but when I do so it's an endless while loop, why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167238/what-does-in-python-mean
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947762/python-why-use-list-when-list-refers-to-same-thing

Comment: It’s not an endless while loop; if you wait long enough you’ll run out of memory and crash ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[:]` means the range from the start to the beginning of the list - it's essentially copying the list (I generally advocate using `list(...)` instead for readability, it does the same job, and works for all iterables, not just sequences).

The issue here is you modify the list while you loop, which then means there are more entries to loop over, so it becomes infinite.

In general, modifying a list while iterating over it is a *bad* idea. Instead, consider a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) to construct a new list.

This code places all words with a length over six at the start of the list, in reverse order. So an alternative implementation would be:

```
words = [w for w in reversed(words) if len(w) > 6] + words
```

Answer (score 4):

`[:]` creates a *copy* of the list. The slice takes all elements and returns a *new* list.

If you loop over the list itself, and keep adding elements to it, you end up with an endless loop. But if you loop over a *copy* instead, then the `for` loop won't see the original list being extended; the copy used for the loop doesn't see the extra element being added.

Answer (score 3):

Because when you use `[:]` it creates a *copy* of the original list, whereas when you omit it, you're looping over the same list, rather than a copy.

If you modify the list as you're looping over it, then you just keep adding to it and it keeps growing, so your loop continues.

If you modify the original while looping over a *copy*, however, then you'll reach the end of the copy and stop (because no new items were added to it).

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you can't iterate over a list and remove elements from this list at the same time.
`words[:]` returns a copy of `words` That way you can modify `words` while iterating through `words[:]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
for i in a:
    if i==1 : 
         a.insert(0,i)
# you can see  endless loop . Because : 
i=1 =a[0]   #after first loop  a=[1,1,2,3,4,5]
# The second loop :
i=1 =a[1] # because   a=[1,1,2,3,4,5]
# after second loop  a=[1,1,1,2,3,4,5]
# So , endless loop , with result a=[1,1,1......,2,3,4,5].
#It very easy .
#If you user :
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
for i in a[:] :
 if i==1 : 
     a.insert(0,i)
#It same  : 
a_copy=a
for i in a:
    if i==1
      a_copy.insert(0,i)
```